# Pandas removing mirror pairs from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
A  B  C  D  E
a  b .1 .3 .9
c  d .2 .4 .5
b  a .1 .3 .9
d  c .2 .4 .5
```

Since 3rd and 4th are same as 1st and 2nd rows, I need them to be deleted. The final dataframe will look like this

```
A  B  C  D  E
a  b .1 .3 .9
c  d .2 .4 .5
```

df.drop_duplicates removes only similar pairs but not mirror pairs. Is there any easy way to implement in pandas to remove such mirror duplicates. Thanks!

Edit:
I just tried drop_duplicates(subset=['C','D','E']) and it will give the result for this data frame. Is there any other solution based on 'A', 'B'.

Comment: The `A` and `B` columns are different. How are you defining "same"?

Comment: @Alex He sees them as "mirrors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.sort` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df.loc[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['A','B']],1),index=df.index).drop_duplicates(keep='first').index]
Out[316]: 
   A  B    C    D    E
0  a  b  0.1  0.3  0.9
1  c  d  0.2  0.4  0.5
```

Comment: Oh, yeah... np.sort()... However I wouldn't use 'last' as 3 duplicated or more values would only remove last. Hence the ~ and keep='first' (default).

Comment: Nice! But don't forget the ~ or you get multiple values with 3 or more again. hehe

Comment: @JaswanthKumar yw~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most efficient as it uses apply, but here is an option:

```
import pandas as pd

data ='''\
A  B  C  D  E
a  b .1 .3 .9
c  d .2 .4 .5
b  a .1 .3 .9
d  c .2 .4 .5'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

mask = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)), axis=1).duplicated()

df[~mask]
```